# How to apply security filters for file uploads forms in wp Wordpress - Forminator

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

`I'm trying to restrict/block access to some type files for particular page.

I'm using [Forminator plugins for creating forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/forminator/) it has function to determine what file types can be uploaded it use mime types. (Although If needed I could use any other)

Problem : it has some limitation. it's only blocking '`dummy.php`' for example if user try to rename a pdf file like this user will be able to upload them :

```
RVQkOcVI8iMC-shell.php00.pdf

wd8n5XJfRo8a-dummy.pdf

yAP4SeoBIeV8-shell.pdf

cv4MRpuxXQuu-dummy.php00.pdf
```

These files should also be scanned or blocked

I checked with AI advised me to do something similar include regular expression pattern or edit .htaccess but it didn't work.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf|docx?|xlsx?|pptx?|jpe?g|png|gif)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>


function custom_upload_check($file) {
 // Check if the file name contains invalid patterns
 $invalid_patterns = array(
    '/-shell\.php[0-9]*\.pdf$/i',
    '/-dummy\.pdf$/i',
    '/-shell\.phtml[0-9]*\.docx$/i',
    '/-dummy\.php[0-9]*\.doc$/i'
);

foreach ($invalid_patterns as $pattern) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $file['name'])) {
        $file['error'] = 'Invalid file name';
        break;
    }
}

return $file;
}

add_filter('forminator_upload_file_prefilter', 'custom_upload_check');
```

Or This :

```
function sanitize_join_us_uploads($file) {
    // Get the file extension
    $ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if the file extension is allowed
    $allowed_types = array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx');
    if (!in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowed_types)) {
        $file['error'] = sprintf(__('Sorry, you cannot upload %s files for this path.', 'your-textdomain'), $ext);
        return $file;
    }

    // Check for disguised PHP files
    $file_content = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
    if (strpos($file_content, '<?php') !== false) {
        $file['error'] = __('Sorry, you cannot upload PHP files for this path.', 'your-textdomain');
        return $file;
    }

    // Check for disguised PHP extensions
    $file_name = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $pattern = '/[-_]([a-z0-9]{2,})\.(php|phtml)(\d{2,})?\.(' . implode('|', $allowed_types) . ')$/i';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $file_name)) {
        $file['error'] = __('Sorry, you cannot upload files with disguised PHP extensions for this path.', 'your-textdomain');
        return $file;
    }

    // Additional sanitization and validation rules can be added here

    return $file;
}

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'sanitize_join_us_uploads');
```

Now I would like to know what is the correct approach, and code ? and where do I apply it and how?
Note : Forminator doesn't seem to have functions.php

I asked chat gpt and gemini and claude I've received more or less the same approach but none seem to works I'm probably doing something wrong.`

Comment: _"Forminator doesn't seem to have functions.php"_ - of course it doesn't. `functions.php` is a file that comes with the _theme_.